# The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not Boolean objects

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures

```
Dim db As Database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase()
    Dim sqlCommand As String = "CategoryListShow"
    Dim cmd As DbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand(sqlCommand)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = CategoryIdTxt.Text.Trim())
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@CategoryResult", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output)
    Dim sqlReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    txtCategory.Text = cmd.Parameters("@CategoryResult").Value.ToString()
    sqlReader.Close()
```

I am calling a Stored Procedure "CategoryListShow". The Stored Procedure has two parameters one is ID which is the Input Parameter and CategoryResult is the output parameter. I am trying to display the value of the output parameters onto this textbox txtCategory.Text.

Error : Yellow screen saying this

The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not Boolean objects.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line where you are setting the value of @ID, change it to this.

```
cmd.Parameters@("ID").Value = CategoryIdTxt.Text
```

You do not need to declare it again.  Just set it's value.  I found the best way of dealing with parameters to be to use the following two lines of code

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProdID", Data.SqlDbType.Int)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
cmd.Parameters("@ProdID").Value = tProdID'obviously don't need this if it is an Output Param
```

Answer (score 1):

#### *Error 1:*

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)
                              .Direction = ParameterDirection.Input)
```

you are trying to add the result of `new SqlParameter(...).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input`, which is of boolean value (it's a comparaison) to `cmd.Parameters`.

You have to initialize the parameters first, then add them to the collection:

#### *Error 2:*

You are adding `@ID` twice.

#### *Error 3:*

Because `@ID` is declared as `Int`, it's value should be of type int => convert `CategoryIdTxt.Text` to `Int` before assigning it to the parameter.

---

You could fix these problems as follows:

```
''' @ID '''
Dim param As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 4)
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
param.Value = Int32.Parse(CategoryIdTxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

''' @CategoryResult '''
param = New SqlParameter("@CategoryResult", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. How can I pass the value of this textbox CategoryIdTxt.Text as an ID input parameter